# Realm. ROS upgrade from 1.0 to 2.0 (from Amazon EC2)

Tags: amazon-ec2, realm, realm-object-server

Want to upgrade from ROS 1.0 to ROS 2.0

About upgrade steps:(https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/latest/#upgrading):

-Guide suggest to create a new folder for the ROS

> mkdir -p /srv/new-root # should be an empty dir

And for the key, seems another folder(not related to new-root, called new-ros):

> mkdir -p /srv/new-ros/keys

Was this a typo?

**Context:**

Actually, the folder containing my keys are:

> ./etc/realm/

And the ROS 1 folder:

> /var/lib/realm/object-server-v2/

Answer (score 1):

That is a typo. So, in you case, it is going to be

```
mkdir -p /var/lib/realm/object-server-v2/keys
cp ./etc/realm/auth.* /var/lib/realm/object-server-v2/keys/
```

Or you can leave the keys where they are and point to them in the server config:

```
ros start --private-key ... --public-key ...
```